# Laravel redirect() in routes.php seem doesn't work.

Tags: php, laravel-5

That is  a blog program,  you can find it  on http://laravelacademy.org/post/2265.html

when I build the grogram  and  then test it, the website comes a 404  error.

```
The requested URL /blog was not found on this server.
```

Could someone tell me where I  make the mistake?

the routes.php  just like that:

```
<?php

get('/', function () {
    return redirect('/blog');
});

get('blog', 'BlogController@index');
get('blog/{slug}', 'BlogController@showPost');
```

the 'BlogController'  is like  that:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Post;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class BlogController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::where('published_at', '<=', Carbon::now())
            ->orderBy('published_at', 'desc')
            ->paginate(config('blog.posts_per_page'));

    return view('blog.index', compact('posts'));
}

public function showPost($slug)
{
    $post = Post::whereSlug($slug)->firstOrFail();
    return view('blog.post')->withPost($post);
}
}
```

If I don't make the code clear ,you can also find it on 
https://github.com/digjack/Blog   thanks!

Comment: if your `/` route and `blog` route does the same thing, why don't you point your `/` route to the same method as it has been done for `blog` too like 
`Route::get('/', 'BlogController@index');`

Comment: Shouldn't routes be defined like so `Route::get('blog', 'BlogController@index');` ?

Comment: @Sid Like what you say , I change the code to 'Route::get('/', 'BlogController@index');'   and the /blog  page  didn't  show the not found problem .   but the next   page  which  show the detail   still  not   found .   The  problem  just the   the code  in the 'routes.php'  just  one  line  in  work ,  the others  doesn't  work.

Comment: @linuxartisan  as  what  you  say ,  I  change   the code to 'Route::get('blog', 'BlogController@index');', but   nothing   happen.

Comment: I pulled your code. It works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this

```
get('/', function () {
    return redirect('/blog');
})
```

with

```
get('/', function () {
    return redirect('blog');
})
```

If it does not work then try this.

Clear your route cache.

Run this artisan command in your cli

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Comment: I have deal  the question.  It's not the problem of the code but  the configuration of the apache2 .   When  Laravel was cooperation  with Apache2, the apache2  should  add  a  rewrite  mod  with command "sudo a2enmod  rewrite". Besides ,  modify  apache2.conf  change the 'allowoverride  none'  of  /var/www  to  'allowoveride  all'  .    Thanks  anyway!  @Ranjeet Singh

Comment: Got it. Mod rewrite should be on.

Comment: Be aware that you cannot cache your routes if you use a function in your routes.